# Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'inlang' undefined at entry 'von_mises_economic_1990' on input line 49

Tags: biblatex-chicago

The contents of my LaTeX file are:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,sorting=nty]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}
  „~\cite{von_mises_economic_1990}“
  \printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

in my citations.bib the case relevant code:

```
@book{von_mises_economic_1990,
    address = {Auburn, Ala},
    title = {Economic calculation in the socialist commonwealth},
    isbn = {9780945466079},
    language = {eng},
  inlang = {eng},
    publisher = {Ludwig Von Mises Institute, Auburn University},
    author = {von Mises, Ludwig},
    year = {1990},
}
```

And I having the warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'inlang' undefined at entry 'von_mises_economic_1990' on input line 49.
```

My version of `biblatex-chicago` is `2017.133.1.0rc4svn44156-5.18` with texlive in Linux.
My version of `biblatex` is `2017.133.3.7svn42680-5.18` with texlive in Linux.
Also the citation give me in this way:

> Mises, Ludwig von. 1990. Economic calculation in the socialist commonwealth
> [inlangeng]. Auburn, Ala: Ludwig Von Mises Institute, Auburn University.
> isbn: 9780945466079.
> How I solve this:

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For what do you need `inlang`?

Comment: @Mensch You mean why I added `inlang` to the citations.bib?. It was an intend to get rid of the warning.

Comment: you should always show a complete example. Such messages depends on the language. You should also tell which biblatex and biblatex-chicago version you use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no field `inlang`. Neither `biblatex`'s standard data model nor `biblatex-chicago` define such a field. So there is little point in adding `inlang = {eng},` to your `.bib` entry.

Your problem is the `language` field in your entry. The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says the following about `language`

> [`language` key list] The language(s) of the work. Languages may be specified literally or as localisation keys. If localisation keys are used, the prefix `lang` is omissible.

The list of valid localisation keys can be found in §4.9.2.18 *Language Names* of the documentation.

`eng` is not on the list of valid localisation keys (nor is it when we add the prefix `lang`), so it is treated as literal input: You say that the language of your entry is `eng`. `biblatex-chicago` then prints that information in the bibliography.

Use

```
language = {english},
```

instead of `eng`.

Then `biblatex-chicago` correctly "understands" the language and even drops the language information for English works in an English document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,sorting=nty]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{von_mises_economic_1990,
  address   = {Auburn, Ala},
  title     = {Economic calculation in the socialist commonwealth},
  isbn      = {9780945466079},
  language  = {english},
  publisher = {Ludwig Von Mises Institute, Auburn University},
  author    = {von Mises, Ludwig},
  year      = {1990},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  „~\cite{von_mises_economic_1990}“
  \printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mises, Ludwig von. 1990. Economic calculation in the socialist commonwealth. Auburn, Ala: Ludwig Von Mises Institute, Auburn University. isbn: 9780945466079.]

Comment: `language=english` is naturally better, but I doubt that it is the source of the warning. This seems to say that the localization string `inlang` is not known, so probably one need `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{inlang={in\addspace}}`. (In current versions it works, but perhaps there was a bug in elder biblatex-chicago).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah, I saw the warning, but then I tried the MWE on Overleaf and could not reproduce the warning with TeX Live 2016, 2017 or 2018. So I figured that the warning must have come from a different MWE (most likely one where the document language is not English) and chose to answer the question that could be answered. I will happily update the question with advice on defining `inlang`, but only if it is necessary (and it is not necessary in the MWE).